# InstallShield or Windows installer corrupted

Tags: windows-7, installshield

Just recently I've been unable to install any software on my Windows 7 machine. Anything that uses InstallShield or the Windows installer will just hang or give a weird error.

I noticed there will be many duplicate `isbew64.exe` processes (like 25) that launch and then just sit there or else a lot of `msiexec.exe` *32 processes, depending on what I'm trying to install.

One piece of software specifically is the Logitech Harmony software. It gives me an ***is_string_not_defined*** error, saying c:\program files (x86):\ the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The other thing I was trying to install was *Battlefield: Bad Company 2*, and that just hangs as well, and then just leaves all the Windows installer processes running in the background after I quit the install process. Very odd.

I've checked well and googled these issues, it doesn't appear to be any sort of malware issue. I feel like it's related to some kind of corrupted installer application.

I've rebooted, deleted the InstallShield folder in program files/common files as some places online suggested but to no avail.

I have no idea what to do, any ideas?

Comment: Is this Windows 7 64Bit?  Do the apps you are trying to install support Windows 7 64Bit?

Comment: Is she getting the uac prompt?

Comment: yeah, i know for the harmony software is supported, as i had it installed before.

Comment: no uac prompt comes up

Comment: I have the same issue on a brand new sony vaio with windows 7 proffessional. All installations hangs with one core fully occupied until I kill it...

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `msiexec /unregister` then `msiexec /regserver` in an elevated command prompt.